# Fail to read configuration with nested keys

Tags: scala, typesafe

With the [Ficus](https://github.com/iheartradio/ficus) library, I am trying to read a configuration file that has the following look:

```
//myfile.conf
macro: {
  micro: {
    a: "a"
    security.something: "b"
  }
}
```

When I try to get a `Map[String, String]` from it, with:

```scala
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus.toFicusConfig
import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ArbitraryTypeReader._

...

myfileConfig.getConfig("macro").as[Map[String, String]](micro)
```

, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$WrongType: myfile.conf @ file:/[XXX]/myfile.conf: 5: security has type OBJECT rather than STRING
```

I did not find a way around that error. What would be a workaround to this error?

------- EDIT -------

I don't know what the structure could be, nor the keys; but I know it will never be more than one dimension objects, thus limited to generics.

So the idea behind is to get the configuration no matter what the structure interpreted as `(String, String)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found something of my conveniance:

```scala
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

implicit class ConfigurationBouiboui(myConfiguration: Config) {

  def load[T](name: String): Map[String, T] = {

    myConfiguration // configuration before target
      .getConfig(name).entrySet() // configuration as path-value pairs
      .map(x => (x.getKey, x.getValue.unwrapped().asInstanceOf[T])) // (dirty) cast value to T
      .toMap
  }
}
```

With:

```
// complex.conf
complex: {
  a: "a"
  b: {
    ba: "4"
    bb: 4
    bc: {
      bca: "bca"
    }
  }
  c: "c"
}
```

, I get:

```scala
val config = ConfigFactory.load("complex.conf")

val configurationMap = load(complex)

println(configurationMap)

//outputs: Map(b.bc.bca -> bca, a -> a, b.bb -> 4, b.ba -> 4, c -> c)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `as[Map[String, String]]` says all values are expected to be strings and as the exception message says, the value for key `security` is not a string (your config is equivalent to

```
macro: {
  micro: {
    a: "a"
    security: {
      something: "b"
    }
  }
}
```

). So you don't want `Map[String, String]`.

But what the fix should be depends on how much you know about expected structure under `micro`: e.g. should there always be an `a` and a `security.something`? Or could there be arbitrary keys? Etc. etc.

Comment: I edited my post with some context.To directly answer your points: I do not know the structure, nor do is there any arbitrary keys.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is much more complex than `Map[String, String]`.

I would use [pureconfig](https://pureconfig.github.io/) which makes it pretty simple to map the configuration directly into `case classes`.

Your example would be:

```
case class Micro(a: String, security: Security)
case class Security(soemthing: String)

import pureconfig.generic.auto._

pureconfig.loadConfig[Micro]
```

Comment: Thank you. I can do that, yes. But this solution does not address non arbitrary keys, which is my main problem.

Comment: arbitrary keys are not the problem - you have arbitrary value types - check https://pureconfig.github.io/docs/configurable-converters.html